# Query data in database to show posts

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[How to foreach 5 posts orderBy DESC show 2 type css, 5 posts from the same category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly7bc.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! please edit your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel Blade allows to use a helpful set of variable like

[**Loop Variable**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable)

When looping, a `$loop` variable will be available inside of your loop. This variable provides access to some useful bits of information such as the current loop index and whether this is the first or last iteration through the loop:

```
@foreach($news as $new)
   @if($loop->index < 2)
     //div with big image class
   @else
     //div with small image class
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1):

okay maybe this question not clear but i try to figure out what you want.you can filter what content will show by just add some condition in your loop

```
@foreach($news as $key => $new)
   @if($key < 2)
     //div with big image class
   @else
     //div with small image class
   @endif
@endforeach
```